# Which one is right, "I decided to pursue it as dream" or "I decided to pursue it for my dream"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

Which one is right,

```
1. "I decided to pursue it as dream" 

2. "I decided to pursue it for my dream"
```

If both of these sentences are not right, can you suggest better sentence for me?

Thank you so much.

Comment: I decided to pursue my dream.

Comment: @Jim Thanks for your answer Jim. However, I want to clarify objective since there is a sentence, which is "Since this major was the only one that gave me responsibility," before "I decided to pursue it as dream."

Comment: You should update your question. But in this case, "I decided to pursue it *as my* dream." Using *as* is correct.

Answer (score 1):

*'It'* remains undefined in your sentence. Therefore, *'it'* must be omitted. You can simply use: 
**"I decided to pursue my dream"**.
 And I don't think you can pursue anything as your dream. However, you could pursue your dream.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood from you question, *it* refers to something you will do in order to achieve your dream, so in this case it should be;

```
I decided to pursue it for my dream.
```